# Showing serverside messages to the user in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-httpclient

I am trying to show the model validation errors and other messages from a ASP.NET Core 2.1 web api controller to the user.

This is the POST action

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Hit hit)
{
    try
    {
        if (hit == null)
            return BadRequest("Hit object is null");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Invalid model object");

        var newHit = _hitRepository.Add(hit);
        return Ok(newHit);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("duplicate key") 
            ? BadRequest($"Et Hit med søgeretningen {hit?.SearchDirection} og ordet {hit?.SearchWord} findes allerede") 
            : StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
```

We have all the usual suspect. Model validation and error handling.

In Angular I have a service with a post method

```
create(hit: Hit): Observable<Hit> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Hit>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.hitRoute}/create`,
      hit
    );
}
```

I have been playing around with the pipe and catchError function but with no luck

```
create(hit: Hit): Observable<Hit> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Hit>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.hitRoute}/create`, hit)
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return new ErrorObservable(
          `Fejl ved oprettelse af nyt Hit. ${error.message || 'Unknown'} `
        );
      })
    );
}
```

The Angular component has a create function that is using the service

```
addWordToHits() {
    const hit = {
      searchDirection: this.selectedBook,
      searchWord: this.selectedItem.word
    } as Hit;

    this.hitService.create(hit).subscribe(
      (data: Hit) => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Hit oprettet',
          detail: data.searchWord
        });
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'error',
          summary: 'Hit kunne ikke oprettet',
          detail: err.message
        });
      }
    );
}
```

The details error message is not from the HttpClient but from RxJs:

```
"Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function"
```

I know it's because the stream is broken by a bad request and not a data stream. But how do I proper show messages from the server to the user?

There are many tutorials on have to build a full CRUD application with Angular

- [Build a CRUD App with ASP.NET Core and Angular](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/26/build-crud-app-aspnetcore-angular)
- [Angular 6 Tutorial: Learn Angular By Building Example CRUD Application](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-tutorial/#Creating_Contacts_Sending_HTTP_POST_Request_Example)

  But none of them are showing how to handle errors.

It most be a very common problem, so how does a real world angular service look like?

This is what I am having right now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

create(hit: Hit): Observable<Hit> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Hit>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.hitRoute}/create`, hit)
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return throwError(
          `Fejl ved oprettelse af nyt Hit. ${error.message || 'Unknown'} `
        );
      })
    );
}
```

---

Created simple code for replicating this

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({})
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.testCatchError();
  }

  testCatchError() {
    this.httpClient
      .get('http://localhost:3000/api/postss')
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.log('inside of catchError');
          return throwError({ msg: 'Hello' });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(`testRetryOperator >>> data >>> `, data);
        },
        error => {
          console.warn('testRetryOperator >>> error >> ', error);
        }
      );
  }
```

}

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it's not working I need the message from the server and it's lost with this approach

Comment: `"Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function"` was due to that

Comment: Yes I know but I am looking for a way to surface the server side errors to the user. How can I access the http response?

Comment: Since, I don't have working code to try on, I was just saying what I can process in my mind.

Comment: It's working I have pasted the working code here, please check the update section

Comment: Then message should be {msg:"404 not found"} the code is catching the error and thats good but it need to pass through the http message like validation errors

Comment: Also, adding an option { observe: 'response' } will include entire response, not just the JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to handle error is by using the `Interceptor`. The best of is that you can handle errors at top level for all API. So need to write same repetitive code to handle http error.

### http-error.interceptor.ts

```
import { HttpEvent, 
         HttpInterceptor, 
         HttpHandler, 
         HttpRequest, 
         HttpResponse,
         HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    return next.handle(request)
       .pipe(
         catchError( (error: HttpErrorResponse) => { 
            let errMsg = '';
            // Client Side Error
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {        
              errMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
            } 
            else {  // Server Side Error
              errMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
            }
            return throwError(errMsg);
          })
       )
  }
}
```

### app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...], 
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap:    [....],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, //<-- provide the interceptor
      multi: true,
    },
    CustomerService,...]
})
```